# Arbitrary ratio sequences on a partition of $\mathbb{R}$ (Partition regularity of fixed ratio sequences)

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, ramsey-theory

```
Background:
```

This question arose purely recreationally and doesn't really fit into any context that I know of.

Let $A \sqcup B = \mathbb{R}$ be a partition of the real numbers into two sets

I have proved that for any positive $k$, either $A$ or $B$ contain $3$ elements $x < y < z$ which satisfy the relation:

$$ z - y = k(y - x) $$

The gist of the proof was a proof by contradiction by brute forcing several forced ratios and then showing the same element had to belong to both $A$ and $B$. My feeling was the proof came out too locally and that there was room for improvement and so I have a more general question:

```
Question:
```

Define a partition of the real numbers: $$\mathbb{R} = \bigsqcup_{j=1}^n A_j $$

Let $k_2, ..., k_{m-1}$ be a list of positive real numbers (possibly an infinite sequence).  What conditions on $n$ and $m$ can I put so that I can guarantee there will be $m$ points $ x_1 < \dots < x_m$ in a single $A_j$ such that $$x_{i+1} - x_{i} = k_i (x_i - x_{i-1})$$ for all $1 < i < m$.

I am stuck for techniques because the original proof was quite crude and it wouldn't generalise.  I also don't have any feel for what the answer will be because the sets you need to look at in this problem aren't at all nice or intuitive.

Thanks!

Update:  It appears this has been solved for general $n$ in the case $m$ is finite by Rado in 1933 (as mentioned in the link Gerry posted: http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=190037) in the affirmative for a general sequence $x_1, \dots, x_m$ although not particularly for the case $x_1 < \dots < x_m$ although this may be a simple extension.

I believe the case for infinite matrices in the general partition regularity problem has not been solved and neither has this particular subproblem when we have an infinite ratio sequence.

Comment: I'd say it fits into Ramsey Theory. I know I've seen similar questions about the integers; given $n$ and some system of linear equations, is it true that in any partition of the integers one part will contain a solution to the system. I think there were papers by Neil Hindman.

Comment: You might be interested in  
Hindman, Neil; Leader, Imre; Strauss, Dona;
Open problems in partition regularity, 
Special issue on Ramsey theory, 
Combin. Probab. Comput. 12 (2003), no. 5-6, 571–583, MR2037071 (2005e:05147)

Comment: Thanks @Gerry, I will have a look

Comment: In that article, it says Rado has proved that a real matrix is partition regular over the reals if and only if it satisfies the columns property.  I believe this answers my question exactly.  Thanks again :)

Comment: And in fact, it means for any choice of $n$ and $m$, the existence of such points is guaranteed because the question I posed is set up in a way where satisfying the columns property is straightforward to see.  This means we can always obtain arbitrary sequences of ratios no matter what partition we use.